# How to open PDF files stored in iBooks on iPad in Adobe Reader

Tags: ipad, pdf, books, file-sharing

I have downloaded PDF files and saved them in iBooks on my iPad. I want to open some PDF files in Adobe Reader but there is no option to do so.

I looked up on internet and it asks for a PC (which I don't have). Is there any way to do so?

I am using iPad Air 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately iBooks on iOS doesn't have the ability to show a share sheet for a document, and therefore can't share to Adobe Reader directly. A workaround is to tap Share → Email, email the PDF to yourself, then use Mail to open the attachment with Adobe Reader.

Comment: Unbelievable! So not user friendly!