# Open safari pdf link in acrobat reader,not in ibooks

Tags: ipad, pdf, mobile-safari

Using an IPAD - (ios-10)
I have Acrobat Reader on my Ipad
I get emailed alink to a PDF - on a microsoft OneDrive account
Or I get a email link to a PDF
Or - I am on some web site that offers a PDF link

I click on the PDF link - and it opens in Safari, and/or I can ask to open it in IBOOK

I need to instead open the link in Acrobat directly some how.
I need to save the pdf locally

I need to mark up the PDF - so that means I would like to use Acrobat Reader instead - but - there is no "share with acrobat reader" - there is no "Open in Acrobat Reader" -

As a trivial example - this link:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf

I want to (a) save the PDF locally - becuase I do not always have internet access where I am using the ipad.

I want to (b) make this available in Adobe Acrobat (becuase I can mark the pdf up) and save the PDF locally.

Key words here are: The PDF file is Saved locally, Opened Locally, and marked up using Acrobat

### What I have tried:

THIS does not work: [How to open PDF files stored in iBooks on iPad in Adobe Reader](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283523/how-to-open-pdf-files-stored-in-ibooks-on-ipad-in-adobe-reader)

WHY? The PDFS are huge - and for various reasons I am forbidden to email them, and I am not suppose to store them in icloud, dropbox, etc.

---

This says it cannot be done from ibooks (wow that seems really stupid)

(I would have a link here to an example, but stack exchange does not allow more then 2 links)

---

THIS does not work: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1615234

While some files are in OneDrive - I do not have a ONEDRIVE account, I'm sent a link to the file and - the one-drive app assumes is MY onedrive account ... it is not - I am given a link to the PDF

---

Other places suggest there is a way to "open in acrobat" by clicking the SHARE icon - acrobat does not show up in the lists, nor do i know how to add acrobat to the list of things I can share with

---

If I open the link in Safari, I can click "Copy to IBOOK" - but I cannot copy to acrobat - how do I do that?

And FYI - I have hit the share button, and acrobat is not on the top half of the list, and it is not on the bottom half of the list and I have no way, and do not know how to add acrobat to the list of apps

==========

Using my PC - and ITunes or other app - to download/move/transfer/sync the PDF file defeats the entire idea here...

Also - I don't always have the PC with me when I need to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Updating to IOS-11 - fixes the problem - adobe now appears in the “Open in Adobe” as a selection.